# Embedded movies, animations in beamer and article document class

Tags: beamer, viewers, media9, embedding, movie15

I would like to use embedded animations and videos in my presentation which has the `beamer` document class. As far as I am concerned there are two packages for doing this **media9** and **movie15**; however, I could not manage to have the PDF reader on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 64-bit play the embedded videos or animations. Although I could see that the video is attached and there is an interactive pin symbol on the page and it can be clicked upon, when that button was clicked it launched the video on a separate window and application which is not what I want. So far I have tried Okular, Adobe Reader, Evince and Qpdfviewer, but none of them were able to play the embedded videos without launching a separate window. The minimal working example is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,letterpaper}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Whispering-gallery mode in a quarter circle:
\includemedia[
  width=0.4\linewidth,
  height=0.3\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  addresource=Circle-m-increase3.mp4,
  flashvars={source=Circle-m-increase3.mp4}
]{}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And the code? Please provide a small sample document we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the issue. [In my experience, you're doing well to get it working at all.]

Comment: @cfr Okay sorry for the inconvenience I have added the MWE.

Comment: is there a reason that your example shows the `article` document class when you are looking for a method with `beamer`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Actually movies work with neither `document` nor `beamer` class.

Answer (score 1):

The code bellow works fine for me. Note the beamer method.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\geometry{verbose,letterpaper}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{Movie test}
  Whispering-gallery mode in a quarter circle:
  \movie[height=6cm, width=6cm, showcontrols, poster]
  {}{Circle-m-increase3.mp4}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Hope it works for you too. :)

Comment: Beamer already loads `hyperref` with tailored options and you shouldn't load `geometry` with it either, I don't think. See the manual for details of both, including out-of-the-box available slide sizes.